# Short story about boy in England who fears new ice age as he notices dawn getting later each day

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for the title/author of this short story which appeared in an anthology. I think it was aimed at children - I read in the 80s in the UK.

The plot line has a boy living in the South of England. In this future, everyone's short term memory is wiped each night - I believe as a way of keeping everyone calm.  He wants to remember, though, so keeps a journal which he hides under his bed.  He notices when reading his entries that dawn is coming later each day.  He doesn't understand the concept of Summer and Winter, so fears that a new ice age is coming (I believe part of the backstory was that an ice age had recently passed and the ice had gotten as far as London).  He is unsure what to do.  Eventually he notices that dawn is getting earlier again and is relieved.

I remember this story well since I had kept a diary when I was younger and it had dawn/dusk times in it.  I wondered whether the author had got the idea from here.

Comment: You wondered whether the author had got an idea from your diary? I feel like there's more information than you're including!

Comment: Many diaries had dawn and dust times printed on each day/week.  So I wondered whether the author had got their inspiration from having a similar diary.  Would be a bit weird if the author had looked at my diary lol!